# How to get the IP address of an LXC container?

Tags: linux, lxc, linux-namespaces

I have started the lxc using lxc-start. Now, how I can get the IP address of the container?

Comment: `lxc-info -i --name containername`. Add -H to get machine readable output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{ print $4,$3 }' /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases | column -t
containername  10.0.3.83
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269588/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-of-an-lxc-container)

Answer (score 0):

try **lxc-ls --fancy** 
it lists all containers, their name, state, ipv4, ipv6 and the autostart flag

Comment: or the short form:   $ sudo lxc-ls -f